# modify php.ini or create new config file

Tags: php, configuration

I'm creating a provisioning script for some servers and part of that needs to load a custom version of php.ini. Should the script replace the inbuilt php.ini file or create a custom config file in conf.d with just the necessary changes?

The changes are mostly for security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: copy & modify necessary parts, if you only want to change some of the settings.

[The `php.ini` configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) is searched in this order (citation shortened). First match is used.

> 1. SAPI module specific location (`PHPIniDir` / `-c` / `php_ini` / `PHP_INI_PATH`)
> 2. The `PHPRC` environment variable. (> PHP 5.2.0)
> 3. Version specific `IniFilePath` Windows registry keys:
>
>    1. `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z]`
>    2. `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y]`
>    3. `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x]`
> 4. `IniFilePath` in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP]`
> 5. Current working directory (except CLI).
> 6. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP (otherwise in Windows).
> 7. Windows directory, or `--with-config-file-path` compile time option.

(Needles to say, but everything with Windows name scapes only applies on Windows.)

Therefore, you should have all the parameters set in the resulting `php.ini`; if a directive is not set, it will fall back to its original [default value](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), not to a value specified in another `php.ini`.

Comment: By 'copy & modify necessary parts' do you mean make the required changes (and just have these changes) to the php.ini file then any values not set will fall back to the default value?

Comment: Yes, but they fall back to default values listed in the [List of `php.ini` directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php). If you want everything else to be as it was in your previous `php.ini`, copy it and modify as needed.